# SSD "healthcheck"?

Tags: linux, ssd

Is there a program for linux to check the health an SSD drive?

Comment: Are you meaning you want to write a program like this, or you're looking to download and use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to do diagnostics for hard drives was always `smartctl`. I guess the same interface should work for SSD... but I've got no experiences with SSD yet.

Answer (score 1):

[SSD Life](http://ssd-life.com) is a good software, but for Windows only :(
As said **liori** above, you can use any SMART control software and look for attribute value, what corresponds to drive health. For example, for Intel SSDs it's a E9 - media wearout indicator, it's value is a drive health (100 = 100%).

Answer (score 0):

You can try new software - [SSDlife](http://SSD-life.com)

Freeware version basic enough and support all major SSD drives and controllers.

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all! The linked site gives a dubious impression; besides it only offers software for _Windows_.