# tools for diagnosing ssd's?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSD “healthcheck”?](https://superuser.com/questions/20288/ssd-healthcheck)

Are there any tools to test if a ssd is beginning to fail? If there aren't any tools, what might I expect to see if a ssd is starting to fail?

I am noticing low performance on one and I don't know if it is the drive or something else and I'd like to rule it out.

OS = Windows 7 Professional

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSD "healthcheck"?](http://superuser.com/questions/20288/ssd-healthcheck) and/or [What diagnostics are safe to run on an SSD drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/232787/what-diagnostics-are-safe-to-run-on-an-ssd-drive)

Comment: Have you looked at the SSD's [SMART attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)? To help solve your specific problem, what SSD do you have, and what OS do you use?